# Java Date gives wrong time

Tags: java, date

Is there any problem with java Date() class it always gives me wrong time for example if my system time is 11 it gives me 12 (it always adds one hour to current system time). How could I solve this problem? I want date to give me the same time as system time.is this related to timezone? I've tried:

```
Calendar startingTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
System.out.println(startingTime.getTime());
```

and

```
System.out.println(new Date());
```

Thanks

Comment: I would hazard a guess that daylight savings are/aren't in effect on your computer...

Comment: Pay attention to the time zone shown when you print the time. Is it right?

Comment: Tell your system to synchronize time against Apple servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be caused by one of two things:

- The date in the underlying operating system is incorrect (but you may accidentally have configured it so you cannot tell).
- The timezone determined by the JVM is incorrect (including that daylight savings information may be outdated).

Perhaps you could add the output of your `new Date()` along with information about what you were expecting and where you are?

Comment: System.out.println(new Date()); gave Sat Sep 03 14:08:37 EEST 2011 while it should be 13:08:37

Comment: What would you expect your timezone to be? EEST smells of daylight savings time.

Comment: I think it is true. but I think java gets the machine time and adds 1hour if time saving is on. I tried to change my machine time 1hour back and it adds one hour also

Comment: where do you live, and what does the operating system report the date to be? see the date command.

Comment: I 'm living in Palestinian territories and I 'm using Mac OSX Lion

Comment: and what does the date command in Terminal.app report the date to be?

Comment: and what is the date Terminal.app reports compared to the one you retrieve in your Java program?

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement Basil's answer, updating TZdata is easy.

First download the Timezone Updater Tool from Oracle at: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-tzupdater-downloads.html

Then run it using the target JVM. I have multiples JVMs in my computer. In my case the command was:

```
sudo /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -l https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now(             // Capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Gaza" )   // Specify time zone by proper IANA-defined name, never a 3-4 letter pseudo-zone such as `PST` or `CST`.
)                              // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()                    // Generate a `String` to represent the value of that `ZonedDateTime`.
```

## Details

The [Answer by Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7292204/642706) is correct.

Here is some modern code to help with debugging.

## Verify current moment in UTC

Regarding Andersen’s first bullet…

See if your computer’s clock was incorrectly set or has drifted. Ask for the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) to avoid the complications of time zones.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

Compare your results to a live web site showing UTC time such as this:

https://time.is/UTC

If incorrect, connect your computer to a reliable [time server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_server) either local to your network or over the internets.

## Check default time zone

Regarding Andersen’s second bullet…

Check the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
String output = z.toString() ;
```

## Specify desired time zone

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Gaza" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

## Update `tzdata`

As Andersen mentioned, your time zone data source may be out-of-day. Politicians around the world have shown an odd predilection for redefining the offset used by their time zone(s).

Most systems get their time zone data from the [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) published by the [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority). This data was formerly known as the “Olson Database”.

You must keep this data up-to-date if any time zones you care about have been changed. You may find time zone data in multiple places including

- [Java Virtual Machine (JVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)
- Database server (such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL))
- Host operating system (such as [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) or [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD))

I looked for a history of changes to time zones in Palestine but that Wikipedia page, [*Time in the State of Palestine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_State_of_Palestine), is incomplete and needs some work.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).